# FormView: View didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I know this is caused when the view has a code path that doesn't return an `HttpResponse`, obviously. I'm new to django, so this may be completely wrong.

Here's the FormView code. Do I need to override `render_to_response`?

```
class AddAdvertView(FormView):
    form_class = NewAdForm

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.campaign = get_object_or_404(Campaign, id__exact = self.kwargs['campaign_id'])

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            pass

    def get_form(self, form_class):
            return form_class(initial = {}, campaign = self.campaign)

    def get_success_url(self):
            return self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', None)

    def form_valid(self, form):
            return HttpResponse('form valid')

    def form_invalid(self, form):
            return HttpResponse('form invalid')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably what you want in your `get` method:

```
 def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
     campaign = get_object_or_404(Campaign, id=self.kwargs['campaign_id'])
     ctx = self.get_context_data()
     ctx['campaign'] = campaign
     return self.render_to_response(ctx)
```

If you aren't doing anything with `post`, you shouldn't have a method to override it. Similarly you don't need to override `get_form`.

Class based views are new in django and their documentation isn't up to par with the other components; hopefully this will change soon. For now, the best place to find out how class based views work is look at what their mixins provide.

For [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#formview), the mixins are [`FormMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin) and [`ProcessFormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.ProcessFormView)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I've noticed the lack of documentation for the class based views. It's quite frustrating that such a nice solution is underdocumented like this.

Answer (score 2):

You should return something from `post` and `get` methods, at least `super(AddAdvertView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)`. In your code `get` just created an attribute (though it should return an empty form), and `post` does nothing at all (though it should process the form). It seems you should not redefine `post` and `get` at all, and retrieve your campaign in the `dispatch` method (don't forget to call `super(AddAdvertView, self).dispatch(dispatch arguments)`)